# Netgear Nighthawk WIFI CABLE MODEM AC1900 Cable Modem Router firmware

Tags: wireless-router

I have read that there is no Router update option on these modems because the ISP does the updating. That conflicts with the Time Warner website which indicates that they do not provide support for personal routers.  How do I get the firmware updated and how do I know when it is time for an update? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the firmware updated and how do I know when it is time
>   for an update?

Since you have the [Nighthawk DOCSIS 3.0 Cable Modem Router - C7000](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/cable-modems-routers/C7000.aspx?cid=wmt_netgear_organic) instead of the [Nighthawk Smart WiFi Router - R7000](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/R7000.aspx), only **Time Warner**, has the ability to update the firmware on it.

You should request to talk to a supervisor in order to explain the siutation.  I have in the past had my internet provider, pushed updates to the modem I purchased from Amazon, so I know Time Warner has the capability to update the firmware on this modem.

*Of course that doesn't mean it currently needs to be updated though.*

> Ideal for fastest Internet cable services like Comcast XFINITY®
>   Blast/Extreme and Time Warner Cable® Maxx data plans.

[Source](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/cable-modems-routers/C7000.aspx?cid=wmt_netgear_organic)

> I have read that there is no Router update option on these modems
>   because the ISP does the updating.

You have the C7000 which is a cable modem, not a router, the Nighthawk router has a R7000 designation.  Although the C7000 functions as both as a router and cable modem, this is typically more accurately, a gateway.